# Need alternative to US Cell phone provider for short codes

Tags: cellphones, philippines

Has anyone found a good alternative to T-Mobile for foreign travel to the Philippines with short codes? Shortcodes are the two step authentication that you get from Google or your bank. Capital One sends me a number code to authorize my account access. I had to call them over and over to get it to work in the Philippines. I'd like to get rid of T-Mobile because they keep charging me randomly for calling US numbers that I never called but that is another question

Comment: hi, @Skycaptain681, welcome to Travel Stackexchange! I'm not quite sure what you're asking; could you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: What are short codes and what is wrong with T-Mobile?

Comment: What's your beef with T-mobile? I've been to over a dozen countries in the last couple of years and T-Mobile has worked like a charm in every single one (including the Philippines).  It's not fast, but it works automatically.

Comment: short codes are the codes you enter followed with a hashkey to get balances and stuff?

Comment: @Hilmar T-Mobile has been charging me randomly for calls to the US from the Philippines that I didn't make. It is like every month or two months they'll throw a $15 charge on my account. I've tried locking it and blocking it by calling their tech support but they had not been any help. I'm sick of them I just want a solution to the two-step authentication for Capital One and my bank and everything else.

Comment: @mic , every clarified the question. It's solving my two-step authentication code problem with T-Mobile.

Comment: @Nean der thal, nice display name. Yes. Short codes are the codes you enter for two step authentication for banks and credit cards and email accounts and everything else. T-Mobile is charging me randomly for calls that I don't make even after I blocked the number. I want to get rid of them but there seems to be no alternative to an American number that is based in America when you're living the Philippines. To get these "short codes"

Comment: Why was an edit to the question which looks like an answer approved? (https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/180508/3)

Comment: Oh, I think the OP approved the edit while they added their own edit. Maybe unintentionally. I'm going to suggest a manual rollback (don't have enough rep to make edits yet), see the suggested edits.

Comment: "Shortcodes are the two step authentication that you get from Google or your bank" – just a clarification on this: short codes are not the codes sent but usually the number they are sent from. This isn't an exclusive use of short codes though. Some services may send 2FA codes via non-short code numbers. And short code numbers can be used to send and receive other things, not just send 2FA codes.

Comment: @NeanDerThal: "short codes are the codes you enter followed with a hashkey to get balances and stuff?" I've answered the question of what a short code is in a previous comment. The thing you're referring to here is often called a "quick code" or "feature code" and the technical name being a "USSD code (Unstructured Supplementary Service Data code)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I receive SMS including short codes while in France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142673/how-can-i-receive-sms-including-short-codes-while-in-france) This question refers to Verizon however T-Mobile may offer similar features or you may try non-carrier specific suggestions.

Comment: Some companies have alternatives to SMS for 2-factor authentication (e.g. a physical authentication device or a separate app), but some probably do not. This seems to be a question about authorisation processes for Capital One, so it maybe belongs on Personal Finance and Money SE. Have you tried contacting your bank?

Comment: @Wing, your edit got aproved, I would appreciate if you now post an answer of what was edited out. (You can use information from comments to do so if needed.)